# Is it better to load data from a .txt file or from a preloaded SQLite database into a private database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm working on an Android app and I wonder if it is better to load data from a .txt file or from a preloaded SQLite db.

When I take data from a .txt file, I do the following:
("insertar" is a function that inserts key and value into db)

```
while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
    keyValue = new String[2];
    keyValue = line.split("_");
    insertar(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
```

I haven't coded a function to copy data from a preloaded database yet.

Do I have any other option in order to be as fast as possible on the first app launch? Which is the most performant method to load data?

Comment: I think it will be much easier to ship app with existing database, you don't have to load records, create schema, etc just load whole db from assets.

Comment: it is a matter of what you do with it. If your app makes modifications to the database, updating will be easier using a text file.

Comment: I ended up using transactions, that reduced times incredibly and it was enough to insert around 8000 records. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do if you want to save a few keywords i woud use SharedPreferences api (this shoud be the perfomantest option). if you want to keep it simple fort he user the see the data i woud take a txt file. If you want to save few data i woud take the datapase. As you can see it depends on the situation.